# Should I reinstall all installed packages?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

While I was upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, `dpkg` was interrupted, I fixed dependency problems, but [a problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243536/ubuntu-20-04-fails-to-write-on-hard-disk-and-freezes-shows-i-o-error) left unsolved. Today, while I was upgrading my system with Synaptic package manager, it crashed, then I again fixed dependency issues. But when tried to run `pip3` , it says:

```
Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I was sure that `python3-pip` is installed, but I followed the instruction which gave this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So, I reinstalled `python3-pip` and `pip3` started working. But I suspect that this has occurred with many packages, so I want to reinstall all installed package with the following command:

```bsh
sudo apt list --installed | sed 's/\// /' | awk '/\[installed\]/{print $1}' | sudo xargs apt install --reinstall -y
```

Should I do this? Is it good idea?

Edit: My question is similar to [Upgrade manager wants me to do a partial upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16494), but I have already done those things but resulted in nothing.

Edit: I want to do this because @heynnema suggested me to reinstall Ubuntu after knowing the whole history of the previous problem, all in comments and chat.

Edit: Thanks to @bac0n, now I can understand which packages are affected after seeing [the output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rDxX463WPz/). Packages that are affected are mostly `python2.7` modules.

Comment: What is your '/etc/apt/sources.list' output? Does it say 'fossa' in place of 'bionic'?

Comment: Your previous problem was faulty hardware, not Ubuntu, so I don't see how this tedious (and disk-intensive) process accomplishes anything useful.

Comment: @user535733 But this time it is software related.

Comment: You are proposing a rather severe solution without explaining what problem it's intended to fix. So far, you have showed us a single package that needed to be reinstalled...and was. Are you encountering similar behavior from other packages?

Comment: @user535733 None till now, but I suspect there are many as dpkg was interupped at middle stage. Also after knowing the whole history of previous problem through comments and chat, [heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) suggested to reinstall Ubuntu. It will reinstall whole system and data won't be lost.

Comment: One or two problems might be worth fixing.  Heynnema seems to know more than I do, so would suggest using his fix.  Your upgrade did not go well and had a crash when updating, so a reinstall would be faster than trying to fix problems as they show up.

Comment: before reinstalling you should take a look at debsums.