# Ubuntu 21.04 freezes with i/o errors, fsck and smartctl does not show errors

Tags: ssd, io

I am seeing this on a Lenovo Flex 5-14. Ubuntu is freezing with message saying the filesystem is not writeable.

I tried fsck and smartctl. Neither showed any errors. I have dual boot and Windows 10 seem to be working fine perfectly.

This is the error that I am getting.
[image]

Comment: Tried remounting? `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: The error happened earlier. Why did the disk where `/var/log/*.log` are written to, get mounted `Read Only`?

Comment: If errors are detected on a *file-system*, a RW mount will flip to RO (read-only as per your messages) so as to prevent data loss.  You should check your logs to see the cause (it maybe a once-off due to power-surge etc esp. if you don't have good line filters & other heavy devices near by that are turned on/off during sessions) then boot a *live* system and check for errors (`fsck`)...  Occurring only rarely is not a problem, but regular occurrences are a symptom of a problem that should not be ignored (and the flipping to RO is a symptom & not the cause!)

Comment: Once the error starts coming, nothing works. The system freezes completely. No, terminal, no Ctrl + Alt + F1. Only thing that works from that point is a hard reboot.

Comment: Once the *fs* has flipped RO you need to limit yourself to commands that read output only, Ctrl+Alt+F1 is by default GUI which will be harder to use (RO) than a text terminal...  SysRq commands to kernel will still function so you can tell your system to cleanly shutdown (unless you've suffered panic which is a different situation you've not mentioned) but I'd usually opt to look for clues as some detail is lost on reboot (eg. `dmesg` but you'll have to limit yourself to using it without piping etc that needs write)

Comment: I have more updates. I booted into windows and did a Lenovo update and it pulled down a BIOS update. That seems to have changed the frequency of the issue. Earlier the issue was happening every 30 minutes or so but now it has reduced to only once in the last 24 hours and that happened when the system was left unattended overnight. I was wondering if this had something to do with power management or anything like that?

I have reported this issue with findings in launchpad as a bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1927866

Comment: Added nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 kernel parameter to grub. That has not had an impact.

Have also disabled fast boot in windows. 

Have also removed remount,ro option for the root partition. Have updated the launchpad bug with all the changes done so far.